# Docker RUN installs don't exist in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, java, docker

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
COPY filebeat.yml /home/docker/filebeat.yml
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y sudo curl vim && \
    adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' docker && \
    adduser docker sudo && \
    echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
USER docker
RUN sudo apt update && \
    sudo apt install -y default-jdk && \
    cd /home/docker/ && \
    sudo curl -L -O --create-dirs https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-8.3.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
    sudo tar xzvf filebeat-8.3.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz && \
    sudo nohup ./filebeat-8.3.3-linux-x86_64/filebeat -c ./filebeat.yml &
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Despite java being installed in the second RUN command, when I attach a terminal and run `which java` I get back nothing. Similarly $JAVA_HOME does not exist etc. Where did java go? What do I need to change in this container to make java not vanish?

Comment: Your Dockerfile will not work anyway. Everything up to the `ENTRYPOINT` is only run _once_, at build time. So Filebeat will _not_ start when you launch the container. // Note that whatever environment variables the JDK package will attempt to set will most likely not be available in the Docker container. A user does not log in and most startup initialization files will not be read.

Comment: A Docker image with Filebeat is already available [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/elastic/filebeat) by the way, maintained by Elastic.

Comment: @DanielB thanks for the tip WRT filebeat. In this case, I need both java and filebeat to be operational on the same container, and whatever mistake I'm making that causes java to evaporate will likely carry over into any other environment, maintained by Elastic or otherwise.

Comment: _"In this case, I need both java and filebeat to be operational on the same container"_ - why? You shouldn't be running two services in one container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many problems with this Dockerfile, where to even begin.

First, the high-level problem: You are attempting to launch a daemon using `RUN`. This will not work. `RUN` is a *build-time* command. It will run *once*, when the image is created. It will *not* run when a container is launched from this image. If you want your container to run something, it must be in `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`. It must run in the foreground.

Next, about layering. You should order the build-time commands in your Dockerfile such that infrequently-changing and “base” steps come first. That means all `apt` stuff, basic configuration like adding the user and also installing Filebeat. What should come *last* is stuff like the Filebeat configuration file. That way, when you change the configuration file, only a single layer has to be rebuilt.

About `sudo`: If you allow your user to do anything using `sudo`, you might as well just use *root* directly. The security benefits will be marginal, at best. In your case, there is no need for `sudo` at all: Just do the system stuff first, install Filebeat to a location that cannot be written to by the user and, maybe also make the config file only readable. Then make Docker start Filebeat with the limited user.

**And now to the actual problem**: Do not, ever, use `nohup` or `&` in a `RUN` command. The ampersand will affect *the entire command* in front which will then not run to completion and instead be killed immediately because the build step is “done”.

You should also be using *default-jdk-headless* by the way, everything else is a waste of space.

Your Dockerfile could look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y curl default-jdk-headless vim \
    && adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' docker \
    && cd /opt \
    && curl -SL -o filebeat.tar.gz https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-8.3.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz \
    && mkdir filebeat \
    && tar --strip-components 1 -xf filebeat.tar.gz -C filebeat/ \
    && rm filebeat.tar.gz \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY filebeat.yml /etc/filebeat.yml
USER docker
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/filebeat/filebeat", "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml"]
```

---

Also check out the [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).